# .append() method with pyserial and arduino gives me ridiculous output

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I' m basically trying to get voltage from arduino, and make an array from them.

Arduino code is below:

```
void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
float voltage = sensorValue*(5.0/1023);

Serial.println(voltage);
}
```

On serial monitor, everything seems fine.

When i try to make an array with python, used this code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM5", 9600)

voltage = [] 

while True:
    volt = ser.readline()

    voltage.insert(volt)
    print voltage
```

Just gave me something but not an array from voltage measurements. I also tried .apppend() and .extend(), same results.

Comment: What _something_ did it give you? You have a list and it will contain each of the measurements. You don't do anything with your list other than insert the text.